# actionperformed firing when button pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Okay, first time asking a question usually i can find these kinds of answers doing a quick search, this one just has me too frustrated.
It's a simple applet that takes hours worked and pay rate to get gross and net pay, most of this is just my trial run (the amount being taken out for net pay etc) but before i go any further i want to get it working.

when the button is pressed nothing happens, not exactly sure why. (More recently when i was trying this-and-that i started getting an NullPointerException in IE, probably has nothing to do with my issues but just throwing that out there too.) ANY help is appreciated, ive tried a few things but im definitely rusty on java!

heres the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;      
import java.awt.*;     
import java.awt.event.*; 

public class ButtonGrossPay extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{

 private JTextField txtHourWork;
 private JTextField txtHourRate;
 private JLabel lblGrossPay;
 private JLabel lblNetPay;

  public void init () {
    Container content_pane = getContentPane ();
    content_pane.setLayout (new FlowLayout ());     

        JLabel lblHourWork = new JLabel("Hours Worked");
        JTextField txtHourWork = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel lblHourRate = new JLabel("Pay Rate");
        JTextField txtHourRate = new JTextField(10);


        JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate Pay");
        btnCalculate.addActionListener(this);

        content_pane.add (lblHourWork);
        content_pane.add(txtHourWork);
        content_pane.add(lblHourRate);
        content_pane.add(txtHourRate);
        content_pane.add(btnCalculate);
        content_pane.add(lblGrossPay);
        content_pane.add(lblNetPay);
        }

 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {

        String firstNumber = txtHourWork.getText();
        String secondNumber = txtHourRate.getText();

        int number1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber);
        int number2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber);

        int gross = number1 * number2; 


        double netPay = 0;
        if (gross >= 0 && gross <= 99.99) {
        netPay = gross - gross * .10;
    } else if (gross >= 99.99) {
        netPay = gross - gross * .20;
    }

    lblGrossPay.setText(Integer.toString(gross));
    lblNetPay.setText(Double.toString(netPay));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're shadowing your variables -- redeclaring them in the class's `init()` method so that all the class JTextFields aren't initialized and thus are null. Solution: Don't do this.

So change it to this:

```
public void init () {
    Container content_pane = getContentPane ();
    content_pane.setLayout (new FlowLayout ());     

    JLabel lblHourWork = new JLabel("Hours Worked");
    // JTextField txtHourWork = new JTextField(10);
    JLabel lblHourRate = new JLabel("Pay Rate");
    // JTextField txtHourRate = new JTextField(10);

    txtHourWork = new JTextField(10);
    txtHourRate = new JTextField(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialise the `JLabels` `lblGrossPay` or `lblNetPay` causing the `NPE`. You should have:

```
 lblGrossPay = new JLabel();
 lblNetPay = new JLabel();
```

Comment: oh duh! i took out the things i had commented out in my actual code and this one one of them, thanks! dont know why i commented it out to begin with!